# Footer em Joomla

Tags: joomla

Preciso de ajuda a mudar a data do copyright de um site, já tentei entrar pelo cpanel mas mesmo assim não consegui encontrar solução.
Nunca trabalhei com joomla[image: ![Footer]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HE3Bz.png)

Comment: Qual versão do Joomla vc está usando?

Comment: Provavelmente essa informação deverá ser alterada no template ou nalgum módulo footer. De qualquer forma serão necessários alguns conhecimentos básicos de Joomla e PHP para efetuar essa alteração sem problema. Em alternativa através de Javascript será possível alterar essa informação também.